# Try to change color of text by using contains filter in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, filter, colors, contains

Try to change color of text by using :contains filter in jquery

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;

    var expense = $('.expense').text();
    var arr = expense.split('€');
    var sortarr = arr.sort();
    var MinExp = sortarr[1];
    var MaxExp = sortarr[8];
    $('td:contains("10,963.89 €")').css('background', 'green');
    //expense.replace(",", ".").replace("€",",");
})
```

But not able change color of text

Please help me

Comment: Could you add your html?

Comment: Please Share your html code

Comment: <td class="customtd3 expense"><strong><font><font>10,963.89 €</font></font></strong></td>

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `.filter()` method :

```
$('td').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().indexOf('10,963.89 €') > -1;
}).css('background-color', 'green');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/filter/